# How to deploy Node.js app without causing downtime

Tags: node.js, deployment, forever

My Node.JS application is running on production server via `forever` daemon:

```
forever start -w --watchDirectory=/path/to/app \
--watchIgnore=/path/to/app/node_modules/** /path/to/app/server.js
```

When I change files contents in `/path/to/app/` directory, the process is restarted by `forever`. While restart takes around 2-3 seconds, the app is unavailable and so downtime occurs every time I deploy a new change. How can I prevent the downtime assuming I have full access to the server?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that manually by using an HTTP load balancer, so you going to create two or more backends that are accessible only by the load balancer (the load balancer is only one reachable by a public address). The next step is to update one server only, while the load balancer controls the traffic to one backend (the available one). After the successful update, you can turn on the updated one and redirect the load balancer to the right backend (the updated), repeat the procedure, and both should be updated without service downtime.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide implementation example?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-haproxy-and-load-balancing-concepts

Comment: Thanks. HAProxy seems like a perfect fit. I've followed the tutorial and found a link to this related tutorial which I found even more appropriate: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-as-a-layer-4-load-balancer-for-wordpress-application-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04 As far as I understood HAProxy even automatically detects unavailable backend and redirects traffic to the one that is available, so all I have to do is to make sure backends are not updated in parallel, is this correct in you opinion?

Comment: Sure, good catch. Is the basic idea, with the time you will find more elegant ways.